# Current time API / Exact time detection via API

Tags: java, android, api, worldtimeapi

Today, for the first time, I am trying to get the right time through the API. I don't understand‚ please help.

I am using the http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/ site to determine the exact time. But I didn’t understand how to use it in JAVA and what codes to write. Please send me a snippet of code or codes. I don't know what codes to write. Thank you!

Comment: Google is your first teacher.refer to [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Where did you run into issues?

- If you want to get the current time, you can use the default Java libraries such as `java.time` for this (see `java.time.LocalDateTime` or `java.LocalTime`). Since you're not guaranteed to get the correct time with an API anyway - say the server is overloaded and response takes a long time. See https://mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/
- If your goal is to just learn to send HTTP requests you can do so with the `java.net` package. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request or https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client if using a more modern version of Java

Comment: Possibly the OP wants to get the correct current time independently of any clock having been set incorrectly on the local computer.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. In this case the request should be pretty straight forward - the API looks very simple.